# Conditionally Strip Characters From String

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to strip the characters ['-] from a string, but not when the string starts with "'t'. Code at present:

```
$name = "'-'-''t van t der Reidjen--'-'-";
$name = preg_replace( '~(^|\s)[-\']+(?!t )(\s|$)~', ' ', $name );
```

Desired results:

```
 "'-'-''t van t der Reidjen--'-'-" =>  "'t van t der Reidjen"
 "van 't der Reidjen--'-'-" => "van t der Reidjen"
 "-van - der -'- Reidjen-" => "van der Reidjen"
```

i.e. It will always leave "'t" at the beginning of the string, even if it is prefixed with a number of [-'] characters, but if "'t" is found anywhere other than the beginning of a string the "'" will be removed.

Comment: one wonders how you got in to this mess in the first place

Comment: I reread it a few times, I think it's **'t** and **'-**

Comment: This is data that has been submitted by individuals. Thus it is full of junk. I have gone to some length to remove the junk, including transliteration and removing ranges, e.g. http://pastebin.com/YmbmBeWT

    There are just a few fine point I have come across later such as  Dutch surnames beginning with ^'t. Previously I had stripped all apostrophes at the beginning of the string. So I have found a solution here to that issue. Thanks.

Comment: Two people gave very helpful answers, yet this is on hold. I wanted some code that would remove leading and trailing apostrophes and hyphens, but leave "'t" at the beginning of the line. This is crystal clear to me as I read the op; and is illustrated with examples. The excessive barring and downvoting on SE sites is becoming tiresome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$name = "'-'-''t van ----''' 't der-Reidjen--'-'-";
$name = preg_replace( "/^['-]+(?!t)/", '', $name );
$name = preg_replace( "/ ['-]+ /", ' ', $name );
$name = preg_replace( "/['-]+$/", '', $name );
$name = preg_replace( "/ '([^']) /", ' \\1 ', $name );
echo $name;
```

**Result**: 't van t der-Reidjen

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
/([-]+)|((?!'t)['])/g
```

**[Online Demo](http://regex101.com/r/sY7cD8)**

The expresion above separated the `-` and `'` since the tricky one was `'` then using look ahead excluded `'t` from the text.

**`(?!'t)`**:  The **negative look ahead** - excludes `'t` matches.

**Note**: These characters `'t`  are being evaluated case sensitive.

Comment: Thank you. This works for everything, except the "'t" in the middle of the string "van 't der Reidjen" needs to be replaced like: "van t der Reidjen"

Comment: It works fine with all expression on the [**online demo**](http://regex101.com/r/sY7cD8).. What is the entire text and how are you testing it?

Comment: I am cleaning up a database of forenames and surnames. So in general there is just one word, but sometimes there are more. Typically I need ['] removed from the begining of lines, but there are a number of Dutch surnames that beging with ^'t. It is being tested just with the regEx above.

Comment: Ahhh that would have helped on the description of the issue :D

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understood what you want, this should solve your problem:

```
/([-]+|(?!^)[']+)\s*/g
```

This Regular Expression will match any `-` one or more time or `'` one or more time if it's not at the beginning of the string due to the [negated lookahead (?!)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). In order to avoid undesired spaces within the string, the special character `\s` will match zero or more (`*`) of them after either `-` or `'`.

Hope it helps.